# What happens after level 30?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-levels, epic-tier

Most of the forum posts I've read say you retire your character at level 30 but wouldn't that make the level 30 Epic Destiny features useless? There must be something after. Why give us cool new features if we'll never get to use them?

Answer (score 16):

The idea of L30 is that you've got *one last thing to do before you die/retire*

So basically, you get to L30, you use your newfound awesomeness to complete your quest to save the world (or multiverse, or whatever), and then your hero rides off into the sunset (or dies heroically, or retires to become a deity or whatever).

L30 is meant to be a *clear end* to your character's adventures.

Comment: If this is true, it is epic in it's lameness (a commentary on 4e, not your answer).  What if I want to keep doing good (or evil, or whatever)?  I dunno.  A difference in philosophy, I suppose.

Comment: @Beska you can always keep playing, there is simply no further to advance, you're already nearly a god. The system's design indicates retirement.

Comment: @Beska, note that retirement means retirement *as an adventurer*. They become demigods, archliches, legendary wizards or whatever. Gameplay-wise, there just aten't (in the core material) any new challenges for a player beyond level 30, nor are there any prescribed benefits for advancing beyond.

Comment: Makes me wish there was a D&D4e: Ascension ruleset.

Comment: Come to think of it, is there an Epic Destiny that doesn't turn you into some kind of demigod, part of reality itself, one of those wacky Star beings, a Time Lord who is their own TARDIS, someone who's a bigwig in hell or something like that? Just an average joe who can do some nice tricks? Beastmaster comes to mind, but that's about it.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs, yes, there are some. Deadly Trickster (PHB1) is "just" a cunning character, with the stories of their exploits being their immortality. Although I think "average joe who can do some nice tricks" is a poor epic destiny for a DnD character since they are way above the average Joes even at level 1.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees Let's take it to chat :)

Comment: @waxeagle I guess I'd rather just keep playing, and not advancing.  If the gameplay doesn't really allow that because of how advanced someone becomes by that point, then *to me* that's broken.  (I probably erred by calling it "lame"...too divisive.  I, personally, don't like it...but I'm just one dude.)

Comment: @Beska there isn't anything but the narrative to stop you. Design expectations don't have to dictate your choices at your table.

Comment: @Beska Think of it like this: imagine an RPG where you were rising the corporate ladder. (What a boring RPG... anyway...) You might get to be a team lead, then a manager, director, senior director, VP, SVP, EVP, President of a large business unit, and eventually CEO. Your career isn't over, but following the path of your rise is.

Answer (score 1):

It is really up to the DM to see if players want to push on ahead. There are still many things DMs can do to create post lvl 30 adventures. Lvl 30 just signifies the end of your character's growth in power (which can be changed) if you want to keep pushing after lvl 30.

Answer (score 1):

There is the option to Homebrew some reincarnation rules in order to recreate your character at level 1 with their base stats and some other cool reincarnation benefits. Think Disgaea, but with Dungeons and dragons instead of Hell.